# Serial downvote: how to make it stop? Tired of having my questions deleted

Tags: discussion, downvoting, deleted-questions

For the second time on askubuntu.com, I got serial downvoted.

The user who downvotes targets questions with no upvote and no answer so that after the downvote the question will automatically deleted. This leads me to think that this is the same user.

Each time, the votes get reversed, but the questions that received the downvotes are deleted. I raised a flag each time a serial downvote happened, but it didn't help.

How to make it stop?

---

Here are the questions that got deleted this time:

- [Dwell clicking software that supports right-dragging and allows to define shortcuts for Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/702575/44876)
- [Log of refused connections by iptables](https://askubuntu.com/q/702149/44876)
- [Disabling the Adaptive Activation area in menus in Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4](https://askubuntu.com/q/703617/44876)
- [Exporting and importing Kickoff Application Launcher's menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/702949/44876)

[image]

Comment: It kind of looks like the downvotes may have been a misguided attempt at moderation. Those questions would probably be closed as OT>>No-repro/obsolete, but maybe the downvoter doesn't have the 3k rep required to cast a close vote.

Comment: @Zacharee1: That would indeed be quite misguided.

Comment: I have undeleted most of your questions (and closed a few of them as duplicates). Still on the matter..

Comment: @jokerdino: Thanks!

Comment: @jokerdino what action was taken in the end?

Comment: @jokerdino I'm still interested to know about it.